# Complete function in WinJS.UI.Pages.IPageControlMembers method

Tags: windows-8, windows-store-apps, winjs

How can I complete function in init before call ready method. My code:

```
WinJS.Namespace.define("Data", {
    source: ""
});

var page = WinJS.UI.Pages.define("/html/page.html", {
    init: function (element, options) {
        createDataSoucre();
    },

    ready: function () {
        document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = Data.source;
    }
});

function createDataSoucre() {
    //blah blah (calculate thousands of calculations)
    Data.source = result;
}
```

When I run, page doesn't render "result" tag. I try use promises but it doesn't work for me:

```
init: function (element, options) {
        return new WinJS.Promise.as(createDataSoucre());
}
```

Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 0):

I tried your code in a simple test project as follows:

```
(function () {
    "use strict";

    WinJS.Namespace.define("Data", {
        source: ""
    });

    function createDataSource() {        
        Data.source = "<ul><li>Item 1</li><li>Item2</li><li>Item3</li></ul>";
    }

    WinJS.UI.Pages.define("/pages/home/home.html", {
        init: function (element, options) {
            createDataSource();
        },

        ready: function (element, options) {
            document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = Data.source;
        }
    });
})();
```

Everything works as expected, with the bullet list appearing on the page.

However, I believe you're asking how to make your createDataSource function asynchronous in itself, so that it can do your "thousands of calculations" off the UI thread and produce a promise that the init function can return. This way, the page loading process will wait upon the completion of those calculations.

What's needed here is to use *new WinJS.Promise* rather than WinJS.Promise.as. The *as* method just wraps a value in a promise so that the value is send to any completed handler you attach, but doesn't create an async function automatically. That's something you have to do.

Let me provide an example from Appendix A of my free ebook, [*Programming Windows Store Apps with HTML, CSS, and JavaScript, Second Edition*](http://aka.ms/BrockschmidtBook2), where Chapter 3 and Appendix A go into all the details about promises. Here's a function that does a long series of calculations using setImmediate to break up the work on the UI thread. (You could also use web workers to put the work on another thread, or use a WinRT component--but I'll leave it to my book to talk about those subjects, which is in Chapter 18 in the section "Implementing Asynchronous Methods").

```
function calculateIntegerSum(max, step) {
    //The WinJS.Promise constructor's argument is a function that receives
    //dispatchers for completed, error, and progress cases.
    return new WinJS.Promise(function (completeDispatch, errorDispatch, progressDispatch) {
        var sum = 0;
        function iterate(args) {
            for (var i = args.start; i < args.end; i++) {
                sum += i;
            };
            if (i >= max) {
                //Complete--dispatch results to completed handlers
                Data.source = "Sum is <em>" + sum + "</em>";
                completeDispatch(sum);
            } else {
                //Dispatch intermediate results to progress handlers
                progressDispatch(sum);                    
                setImmediate(iterate, { start: args.end, end: Math.min(args.end + step, max) });
            }
        }
        setImmediate(iterate, { start: 0, end: Math.min(step, max) });
    });
}
```

You can do something similar for your own process. The key here is that when your process is complete, you have to call the completeDispatch function that's given to your initializer. In the code above I'm also putting the result into Data.source.

With such a method, your createDataSource function can look like this:

```
function createDataSource() {
    return calculateIntegerSum(100000, 2);
}
```

Because calculateIntegerSum returns a promise and is implemented to be async, createDataSource will return a promise that you can return from init:

```
init: function (element, options) {
    return createDataSource();
},
```

I tried this out in a project and it works just fine, with the page loading waiting upon the calculations to complete.